# Sectioned UITableView gives unexpected behaviour in accesoryview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, accessoryview

I've got a UITableView containing three sections.

- Section 1 has one cell containing a UISwitch `failAtLaunch` in its accesoryview
- Section 2 contains the items from the failSounds array and has a singular checkmark for the selected item (sound in this case)
- Section 3 contains a button.

You can see below how I configure the cells..

The problem is that the table gives strange behaviour. Whenever I scroll up and down the tableview, with cells moving in and out of view, some cells in section 2 get the UISwitch `failAtLaunch`in their accesoryview.

Can anyone help me understand why this is?

Thanks in advance!

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
     //....blablabla...

        // Configure the cell...

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        NSString *theSound = [prefs objectForKey:@"pickedFailSound"];
        NSUInteger index = [failSounds indexOfObject:theSound];


        if (indexPath.section == 0){


            failAtLaunch = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 7, 100, 30)] autorelease];
            [cell addSubview:failAtLaunch]; 
            cell.accessoryView = failAtLaunch; 
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

            if(![prefs boolForKey:@"failAtLaunch"]) {
                [failAtLaunch setOn:NO animated:NO];
            } else {
                [failAtLaunch setOn:YES animated:NO];
            }

            [(UISwitch *)cell.accessoryView addTarget:self action:@selector(setIt) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Instafail";

            return cell;

        } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {

            NSString *cellTitle = [failSounds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.textLabel.text = cellTitle;

            if (indexPath.row == index) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }

        return cell;

        } else {

            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"buttonCell"];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"buttonCell"] autorelease];
            }


           cell.textLabel.text = @"Hold to record fail sound";
            UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(230.0f, 4.0f, 60.0f, 36.0f);
            [btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(recordAudio) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(stop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];


           return cell; 

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is from the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: use different static strings for each type of cell.

Answer (score 0):

It's your blah blah blah section.  I think you are probably using the same reuse-identifier for all 3 types of rows, and not clearing them out prior to re-use.
 So when you instantiate a new tableViewCell, you need to switch on section and give each one a unique identifier.
 What I usually do is tag every view that I add to a cell with a tag like "CLEAR_ME_OUT" that is defined as some large arbitrary number.  Then when I re-use a cell, I loop through the sub-views and removeFromSuperview all cells with that tag.  That way it's nice a clean for re-use.